# combining multiple collection group queries

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have set up a firebase database like such:

```
food (collection)
  - 10/19/2021 (document)
     - Breakfast (collection)
       - Food Item 1 (document)
     - Lunch (collection)
       - Food Item 1 (document)
     - Dinner (collection)
       - Food Item 1 (document)
  - 10/20/2021 (document)
     - Breakfast (collection)
       - Food Item 1 (document)
     - Lunch (collection)
       - Food Item 1 (document)
     - Dinner (collection)
       - Food Item 1 (document)
```

I now want to query for all food items that match certain criteria, i.e. `FoodItem.calories < 500`.

How should I set up this query?

I wanted to use a [Collection group query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) but this only seems to work for 1 meal: E.g. breakfast, lunch, or dinner but not all three.

Should I set up 3 queries, 1 per meal and then merge results, or is there a cleaner way?

```
const breakfast = query(collectionGroup(db, 'breakfast'), where('calories', '<=', '100'));
const querySnapshot = await getDocs(breakfast);
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Collection group queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) work over all collections with a given name. Since you have named your collections after the meal they cover, you can't use a single collection group query to read across all meals.

The common solution is to use a single name for all these collections (e.g. `meal`) and then store the type of meal (e.g. `Breakfast`) in the parent document of the food items in that meal.

The alternative is to perform a separate collection group query for each meal type (e.g. `Breakfast`) and merge the results in your application code..

Comment: Thanks for the answer Frank! I am having a hard time picturing how the structure would look like with your "common solution". Would you mind elaborating or creating a tree-like diagram?

Comment: I have also added pictures of what the database structure looks like to avoid confusion about which elements are collections / documents.

Comment: The problem in your model is that `Breakfast` is a collection, where I'd typically expect it to be a document. In cases like this I often end up with a default/dummy document in my parent collection, e.g. `/food/{date_doc}/default/{meal_doc}/items/{item_doc}`. What I call `default` here, could also be called `meals` or something more meaningful, it's mostly there to ensure you end with `Breakfast`, `Lunch` etc as *documents* instead of collections.